# Calculating minimum hamming distance of a code

Tags: algorithms, information-theory, binary

We use hamming code of (7,4,3); Given 4 bits of information, we'll add 3 bits of parity, and one more parity bit for the 7-bits code.

Given $x_3,x_5,x_6,x_7$
$x_1 = (x_3+x_5+x_7) \mod 2$
$x_2 = (x_3+x_6+x_7) \mod 2$
$x_4 = (x_5+x_6+x_7) \mod 2$

For example,
for $0010$ the correspond codeword is $10101010$.
for $1001$ the correspond codeword is $00110011$.

So, I was asked to calculate the minimum [hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of **the code**. A naive way would be calculating the distance between each pair of codewords and taking the minimum value, and giving a small example using the naive way.

Thanks!

Now, is there a better way doing it? like a formula, or set of rules?
I've read several articles about this issue, and all they do is explaining what is a minimum hamming distance of a code.

Comment: Your code is linear, so you can calculate the minimum (non-zero) Hamming weight instead. Checking all the 16 combos won't be too harrowing a task. Particularly if you first observe that $(x_3,x_5,x_6,x_7)=(1,0,0,0)$ gives rise to a weight three word. Thus the minimum cannot be higher than three, and its only a matter of checking out that one and two don't occur. There are four inputs of weight 1 and 6 of weight two, so that's only ten checks.

Comment: There are theorems, rules and formulas governing special classes of codes. But in general no polynomial time algorithm for approximating the minimum Hamming distance of a long code very accurately is known.

Comment: OK, that's interesting. Suppose I'll go with the second way, how can I efficiently validate $d\ne 1,2$?

Comment: Consider the possible input weights. If exactly one of $x_3,x_5,x_6,x_7$ is non-zero, then at least two of parity bits are non-zero (each information bit affects at least two parity bits). If exactly two of the information bits are non-zero, between them they cannot make all the parity bits zero. You can more or less tell this at a glance after a bit of practice, but I encourage you to think it through and write up an answer... So in neither case will you get words of weight $<3$.